# Extjs Tree editor - disable single click to edit

Tags: extjs

I am using tree editor. I need the tree node to become editable only when it is double clicked. So far I have done this

```
  var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
      root: this.getChildren(),
      height: 300,
      loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
      useArrows: true,
      autoScroll: true,
      listeners: {
          dblclick: onTreeNodeDblClick
      }
  });

  var treeEditor = new Ext.tree.TreeEditor(tree, {}, {
      cancelOnEsc: true,
      completeOnEnter: true,
      selectOnFocus: true,
      allowBlank: false,
      listeners: {
          complete: onTreeEditComplete
      }
  });

  onTreeNodeDblClick: function (n) {
      treeEditor.editNode = n;
      treeEditor.startEdit(n.ui.textNode);
  }

  onTreeEditComplete: function (treeEditor, o, n) {}
```

I have searched the api to find something like "clicksToEdit" which we use in editor grid but cant find anything. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ext.tree.TreeEditor adds two event listeners (beforeclick, dblclick) to tree
so you may unsubscribe its from tree

```
tree.on('afterrender', function() {
    tree.un('beforeclick', treeEditor.beforeNodeClick, treeEditor);
    tree.un('dblclick', treeEditor.onNodeDblClick, treeEditor);
})
```

Comment: Helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From API of Ext.tree.TreePanel:

`beforeclick : ( Node node, Ext.EventObject e )`

`Fires before click processing on a node. Return false to cancel the default action.`

So you could do this:

```
var tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
  root: this.getChildren(),
  height: 300,
  loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader(),
  useArrows: true,
  autoScroll: true,
  listeners: {
      dblclick: onTreeNodeDblClick,
      beforeclick: function() { return false;}
  }
```

});